# How to bind some function to non exist element?

Tags: jquery, dynamic-binding

My problem: after load some element via ajax, i bind some on-click function, but when user will load few times that same element, binded action will be repeat (not replace, at least that it looks like). I tried `unbind`, or `click(function(){return false;});` but that complete remove clic action from element...).
What is standard solution of that kind of problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For most events you can use [`live()`](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/live) (jQuery 1.3+):

```
$("td").live("click", function() {
  // do stuff
});
```

This will bind a click event to `<td>` elements that come into existence after you run this code as well.

This is a much cleaner solution than trying to bind/unbind and ensure you don't have the same event bound twice to a particular element.

Comment: Thx, +1 and `correct answer`, but a little problem still is: with `not` it suppose to don't work... `$("...").not("sada").live("click", func...`.

Comment: That's going to be a little more problematic. What exactly are you trying to do? I can perhaps suggest a way that'll work.

Answer (score 1):

if you're using jQuery 1.3.2, you can use `$('').live('click', function() {});` to have any elements that match that selector have the action.  It keeps the event around even with new elements.